# need help - IWindowsFormsEditorService in WPF? or possible another alternative solution to my issue

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, propertygrid

I've taken the following code and extended it to my code:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/PropertyGridEx.aspx

My code is a program written in WPF while the example is in Windows Forms Application

**My code-**

http://pastebin.com/phshqYwY

**My problem-**

the "IWindowsFormsEditorService" is only for UserControl windows that made by Windows Forms Application so the following row:

```
wfes.DropDownControl(ucUseValue);
```

**Shows the following errors:**

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Design.IWindowsFormsEditorService.DropDownControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Visual_Command_Line.UserControls.ArgumentEditor.UseValueArg' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

**So, i thought of two Solutions - tell me if one of them is possible:**

1. Is there any alternative to "IWindowsFormsEditorService" in WPF?
2. Is there any possible way to convert my UserControl which is "UseValueArg" to a System.Windows.Forms.UserControl type of UserControl?
3. Creating a UserControl that is of type System.Windows.Forms.Control and not of WPF (something which I already tried and it works, though it's seems stupid to have Windows Forms Application in a WPF)

**Thanks in advanced,
Din**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though my answer is a little 'off' in the topic, you might want to try: http://wpg.codeplex.com/